# How can I Execute a Function when Windows Shut down

Tags: c++, windows

How Can I execute a function when Windows shutdown. Here is my scenario, I am mounting a drive using [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa385413)  function in my application. Now I want user to set the option if the drive will be mounted on next system startup or  not.

If he selects , not to mount on next startup , then I need to remove the drive using [WNetCancelConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385427%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) , but this should only happen when user shutdown the system.

I can only think of only solution. Create a service which will check the user option and then decide whether to mount the drive or not.

Are there any other ways to go ahead with it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a main window (even an invisible one) that can process messages, you can handle the WM_ENDSESSION message.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: What is Main Window(even an invisible one) ?

Comment: Even better than invisible, create a message-only window. Call `CreateWindowEx` and pass `HWND_MESSAGE` as the parent.

Comment: @MSalters, all this win32 API stuff I've done in my time and I never knew of HWND_MESSAGE.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you can make your app into a Windows service (or have your app communicate state with one that you provide) you can perform required actions on receipt of SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN in your [service control handler function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685149%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  This would decouple your app that handles user interaction from the shutdown handling, which requires something to be running all the time (what if the user logs off?).

Answer (score 0):

explorer.exe is the GUI process of windows which *usually* only gets shut down if Windows shuts down (exceptions have to be made for certain error conditions). You could listen on the WM_DESTROY window message for the process ID of explorer.exe and dismount then.

Comment: Who's doing the listening, and how do you ensure that process is still running?

Comment: I'd say my application listens in it's window loop. And if it's not running, I'm pretty sure no solution can do anything about it being closed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I can think of is to:

1. Register your program to auto Start up (when PC starts). [Here's](http://ask-leo.com/auto_start_how_do_i_run_a_program_automatically_when_windows_starts.html) a tutorial on howto.
2. Store the user option (as mentioned above) in a repository or registry (if you know how). When your app would have started, you can read your registry and act accordingly.
3. For shutdown, your application will have to hook itself on a SystemEvent to detect shutdown (then you can act accordingly). [Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/8c58edc5-131e-40e9-b649-074cdba2309b) an example on howto (C#). For C++, you can listen to [**WM_ENDSESSION**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

I hope that my 2 cents can help you.

Comment: The [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/8c58edc5-131e-40e9-b649-074cdba2309b "Detect Machine ShutDown") shows detecting system shutdown  using C# ,Managed code ,I am using C++ for my application